# How to update data in Firebase Realtime Database with Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to change a boolean value in my Realtime Database with Cloud  Functions, where each user has a variable called `DailyGift`. And when this equals true, it needs to be changed to false.

This is what I have so far:

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

var db = admin.database();
exports.ChangeStatus = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

});
```

Comment: Cloud Functions are essentially managed Node.js script. So you can [use the Admin SDK in there to read from the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data).

Comment: Before asking someone to write your code for you, I suggest you make an attempt at doing small amounts of work in order to get acquainted with the system, then work towards your goal with what you've learned.

Comment: when reading "daily" ...I'd think of the [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/).

Comment: Doug Stevenson i am not trying to someone write my code i just want help , when i search in google i only found methods like OnCreate OnDelete OnChange and i don't need that i need to read and change data every day  no matter if my data change or not

Comment: If you solved your problem then answer it in answer section and then accept your own answer

Comment: Please don't include your solution in your question. Questions are for questions and answers are for answers :)  There is absolutely nothing wrong with answering your own question.